# Filter a secondary datasource in infopath

Tags: 2010, infopath

I'm having some issues with InfoPath. This is the case:
On SharePoint we have 2 lists:

- ListA
- ListB

ListB contains a lookup field to ListA. I customized the displayform of ListA with Infopath and now I want to show the items of ListB on that form filtered by the lookup column.

I want something like this:

ListA: Title=demo
       Date=xx/xx/xxxx

Items in ListB that belongs to Title=demo

- ListB-item1
- ListB-item2

I've added a secondary datasource to the form that points to ListB but I can't see how I can filter the datasource?

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely rely on filter values to filter out other sources. Have a look at this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/filter-the-data-that-is-displayed-in-a-control-HA010024281.aspx (start with XPath filtering and add additional conditions).

Comment: I want to display the data in a repeating section, not a control. That's the problem. I cannot filter the repeating section when the data comes from a secondary datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use InfoPath to filter what appears in the form based on your selection of the lookup field. In InfoPath on the fields that will contain the data from the other list you can select what appears dependent on the selection made in the lookup  field. How you do this depends on the type of field; if it's a drop down then you filter the choices; if it's a text box then you build the string for the default value. No code needed either, it's all a case of choice boxes when building the properties of the field.

If you go to my blog www.edutechnow.com there should be some videos I recorded showing how we did it for the School I work at.